# Geoexplorer (Opengeo Suite) cannot upload data

Tags: geoexplorer, boundless-suite

i am following the tutorial how to create a simple map. However, I got stuck in the step to upload the data. It gives me an error and I dont know why (see photo). I zipped the shapefile with all the respective other files and uploaded it. Doesnt work. This is why I also added a Spatial Reference. The data is WGS84 --> EPSG:4326. [image]

I just downloaded and installed Opengeo Suite. So its the latest version. I have Windows 7, 32 bit on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Your zip file must have 5 or more files inside for specific shapefile and name of zipfile must have filename as all files have. I think that prj file is also required, maybe even xml. I have problem with dimmed part of dialog box under Options or Optionen. EPSG can also be yours specific (like in prj file) not necessary 4326 or WGS84 because on the fly is enabled here, too.